# Why this code output Event object whatever element

Tags: javascript

Why this code output Event object whatever element

```
    <html>
<script>
   </<script type="text/javascript">
const anyelement =document.querySelector('#khaled')
anyelement.onclick = () => cosole.info(event);
</script>>
```

Comment: Yep i got it 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't declared `event` as a local variable or parameter, it's a global variable, equivalent to [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event). This is an Internet Explorer variable that some other browsers have copied. While an event handler is running, it contains the current event.

Firefox hasn't copied this variable, so your example won't output the `Event`.

Comment: But it just do even not include any parameters inside

Comment: Why does that matter? You haven't declared `event` as a parameter, so it's the global variable. It's the same as `window.event`.